# Why urxvtc doesn't accetp zsh functions when called with a "-c" argument?

Tags: zsh, function

In order to launch a new terminal and run a zsh function on it, I am trying to run the following
command from within an `urxvtc` terminal (the `urxvtd` is running as a `systemd` service)

```
     urxvtc -e zsh -c "my-zsh-defined-function"
```

which doesn't work as the function is unknown. I need to explicitly source my `zshrc` to make it work

```
     urxvtc -e zsh -c "source ~/.zshrc; my-zsh-defined-function"
```

The problem is, I don't understand why. Shouldn't `zsh` source `.zshrc` as when I run `urxvtc`,  and
then I type `my-zsh-defined-function` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't, since you're not running `zsh` interactively. Quoting [`man zsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/zsh.1.html) (section `STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES`):

> [I]f  the shell is interactive, commands are read from **/etc/zshrc** and then **$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc**.

You could try using `-i`:

```
-i     Force  shell to be interactive.  It is still possible to specify
       a script to execute.
```

Comment: Well, doing `urxvtc -e zsh -c 'zsh -i -c my-zsh-defined-function'` works fine, thanks